# Should I edit the request to mark all other questions, similar to this one, as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I understand what the OP is trying to do in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php?noredirect=1#comment46811951_29308898) but it seems a bit over the top to ask:

> "Please close any question that is not significantly different as a duplicate of this one."

I have already marked this one as a possible duplicate.

Should I edit the question to remove the language and let it stand on its own?

Comment: Follow the same guidelines that you would for any other duplicate question: best duplicate wins. Though, how do you define which is "best"? most upvoted question? most upvoted answers? most views?

Comment: "Best" is subjective to the reader. While you find an answer perfect @KevinB I might find it lacking. Of course I know I am preaching to the choir here ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove that from any question you see.  It's simply noise.  If a question is a duplicate, readers should be voting/flagging to close without being told.  Nobody needs the author's permissions to vote/flag to close.

Comment: After some reasoned discussion the OP made the edits himself. The question itself is still much too broad.

Comment: Seeing what you answered here; I've been grilled a few times about closing questions that were obvious duplicates. Grilled as in: *"Fred, It would be faster to just answer the question rather than closing it as a duplicate"*. A great big *"whiskey tango foxtrot"* there I might add. Ok, so "grilled" wasn't the right word: more like "questioned".

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is the unfortunate reality of the situation that it often *is* easier to answer duplicate questions every time, instead of closing them.  It's way worse for the site, as it spreads out the information, reducing the quality of the answers to all of the questions, often dramatically.  Users are also rewarded for answering, rather than voting to close, even though they're *making the site worse* by doing so.

Comment: @Servy I guess I'll have to wear gloves for that "double-edged sword" the next time *lol* But the thing is here, is that I got downvoted for an answer I gave for this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35786981/ where I spent a lot of time writing it up in order to "answer" the question. I admit that I could have easily closed it as it was marked as a duplicate by chris85 http://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85 and closed by YCS. I suspect he gave me that downvote either in spite and/or because I didn't give it "the gold". Funny how the other one did not get a downvote though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So you knew the post was a duplicate and you answered anyway?  Then yeah, you weren't helping the community by answering it, and you knew it, and did it anyway.  Why are you surprised that someone else felt the same way and voted accordingly?

Comment: @Servy I'm not quite understanding what you said earlier then. I thought you said that it was easier to answer it rather than closing it? and YCS is just guilty as I in a few of his answers too. Yet, he didn't close them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it is often (but not always) easier to answer than to close.  It makes the site a worse place, but it is easier.  You chose to do what was easier for you, rather than what was most helpful to everyone but yourself.

Comment: @Servy I didn't think of myself here and I'm not in this for the rep points, if that's what you're thinking. If I were, I'd of (easily) put in an (lazy) answer like the other one given with hardly any explanation. Had it been the case, I'd of taken that downvote with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Servy Take this answer of his for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/35700156/ where he references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php which is often used to close questions as a duplicate. If I were to close that question right now, he'd be all over me and crying about in meta. He's done it before. So, why didn't he just close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @Fred-ii- So because one person answered a duplicate question once, it's okay for you to do it whenever you want?  That's not how it works.  The fact that someone else answered a question you think is a duplicate once doesn't make it okay, or helpful, for you to answer every duplicate question you come across instead of voting to close it.